# How to solve unhashable type error for boxplot?

Tags: python

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.  Any advice on the solution for the syntax below? Thanks!

```
f1_scores = []

for cutoff in np.arange(.1, .9, .1):
   clf = RandomForestClassifier(15, random_state=int(cutoff * 10))
   f1_scores.append(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, scoring=custom_f1(cutoff), cv=10))

sns.boxplot(np.arange(0.1,0.9,0.1), f1_scores)
sns.boxplot(float(np.arange(.1, .9, .1)), f1_scores)
sns.despine()
plt.xlabel('cutoff threshold')
plt.ylabel('f1 score')
plt.title('F1 score varies with different cutoff thresholds')
plt.show()
```

Searching for conversion of the array